# What is "number" in elm

Tags: types, elm

I'm getting confused by `number`. It seems to be a type, similar to a supertype of `Int` and `Float`, like [java.lang.Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), but:

- It is written in lowercase and thus is syntactically similar to the name of a value (I use 'value' to avoid using the designation 'constant variable')
- One can actually declare a value called `number`.

Observe:

```
> 1024
1024 : number
> 1024.0
1024 : Float
> floor(1024)
1024 : Int
```

Let's use a value name `number`:

```
> number = 144
144 : number
> number
144 : number
> number = floor(144)
144 : Int
> number
144 : Int
```

And also:

```
> Result.Ok 12 
Ok 12 : Result error number
> Result.Ok 12.0 
Ok 12 : Result error Float
> Result.Ok (floor 12) 
Ok 12 : Result error Int
```

What is `number`?

Is it a union type that has been awkwardly named? An infelicity in the syntax?

(Whimsical aside: Why not have a special syntax for "things from the universe of types" like, `↑Int` and another for for "things from the universe of metatypes" like `⇈X`. Elm, being by design annotation-poor is sometimes hard to decipher.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand, `number` is a kind of built-in type class, similar to an interface in Java that describes which operations can be performed on the types that implement the interface. But where in Java an interface from a consumer point of view is specified as an ordinary type, a type class is a constraint on a type variable, specified by convention using "magic" type variable names such as `number`  or `comparable`.

In languages with "proper" type class support, such as Haskell, you would specify the constraint separately, i.e. `Number a => a -> a`. But in Elm, having just a few built-in type classes, the burden of having to learn the concept and syntax for this just to be able to use a few fairly intuitive built-in type classes I think is seen as unnecessary. While you probably won't intuitively understand exactly what it means, you should be able to understand it well enough to at least be able to use most functions taking `number`s or `comparable`s as arguments. Its exact meaning can then be explained later (though I do sometimes wonder how much later the official explanation is going to be...).

I hope this sufficiently answers your question, but let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks. So it's a pragmatic "description" that ... does what its name evokes. I can live with that. I found the small chapter on "Constrained Type Variables" here: [Reading Type](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was not aware of that. it must have been added with the 0.19 update to the guide. So now there is _something_ official about it at least :)